# Finding the derivative of this complex function

Tags: calculus

I need to find the derivative of the function $h:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and prove it is harmonic $$h(z)=\log\left|\frac{(z-a)(z-b)}{(z-c)(z-d)}\right|$$

I know how to prove it is harmonic but I'm having trouble with the derivative.

Comment: Divide and conquer: The Laplace operator is linear and local. That logarithm is a sum of logarithms of absolute values like $\log|z-a|$. If the Laplace of each of them is zero then that of the sum is also zero. To compute the Laplace of $\log|z-a|$ you can also compose with $z+a$, since by the chain rule a translation only multiplies by derivative by $1$. So, it is enough to prove that $\log|z|=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)$, where $z=x+iy$, is harmonic.

Comment: $$ \log\left| \frac{(z-a)(z-b)}{(z-c)(z-d)} \right| = \log\left|z-a\right| + \log\left|z-b\right| - \log\left|z-c\right| - \log\left|z-d\right| $$ That can simplify finding the derivative.

Comment: Just what kind of differentiation is involved doesn't seem clear.